# s3fs and fuse: failed to open /dev/fuse: Permission denied

Tags: amazon-s3, fuse, s3fs

Just installed Debian 6 box. I wanted to mount my S3 bucket for some backups. 
So I followed instructions for http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/ .

1) I installed all perquisites asked in installation instruction.
2) Compiled and installed s3fs.
3) Configured by putting my credentials to passwd-s3fs.
4) Tried to mount my bucket: "/usr/bin/s3fs backupejekabsons /mnt"

I get error message "fuse: failed to open /dev/fuse: Permission denied"
After googling a bit, I found out that I need to add "fuse" group to my account.

I added a group and relogged. Didn't help.
I tried to reboot VM, still no result.

Some output that may be helpful:
1) edgarsj@1310-700-4568:~$ groups
fuse edgarsj rvm

2) edgarsj@1310-700-4568:~$ id
uid=1001(edgarsj) gid=111(fuse) groups=1002(edgarsj),111(fuse),1000(rvm)

3) edgarsj@1310-700-4568:~$ ls -la /dev/fuse 
crw-rw---- 1 root fuse 10, 229 Aug 12 15:36 /dev/fuse

I also tried to add this group to root and run as sudo. Same result.

Thanks for your attention, mates. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this discussion help? http://groups.google.com/group/s3ql/msg/8cf247561362f378

Basically, the VM host may not be actually giving you permission to use /dev/fuse.

They've added to solution to the s3ql FAQ: http://code.google.com/p/s3ql/wiki/FAQ

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Posted a ticket to my VPS provider. I hope they will grant access.